# Is it possible to make a HTA (html app) that can search a text

Tags: html, hta

I needed to make a html search box with a buttonclick that on click it will search the given sentence in .txt file(s) and show them? If yes how and is it possible to make one that works with realtime input?(changing the searched input automaticly as soon as something in input changes) thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please show what you've tried ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to make a web app? Your question is undefined.
You can't do such a thing using HTML (HyperText Markup Language), it's not a programming language. The thing you do in HTML is form a `box/text field` in which you type.

And by the way, you already have such a function in all browsers, click `"CTRL+F"` on any page, and type something, it works realtime using the input.

Comment: Im looking to make a desktop app wit html it will be for personal use and i wont be using browsers for it thats why i need this. I already know how to make an input box and button but I don't know if its possible to make that button find a text in a document and show it in the page. By not using browser i mean ill use .hta which opens it same as browser so its not much of a difference.

Comment: If its not possible with which language can i do that i have very little experience and its gonna be for personal offline use (school stuff)

Comment: So you're looking to make a desktop app with HTML..?
Okay first:
Learn what terminology you're using. 
HTML is NOT  a programming language and you CANNOT make desktop programs with it.

Comment: For a desktop program, I would personally recommend Java, a programming language. And it can be done in Java fairly easily.
However, if you want to make programs, learn the whole programming language, not only copy and paste to build your program. 
And you can also search in the documents using ctrl+f...

Comment: Will do that thanks( it was only supposed to find a text not do bunch of stuff to be an exact program) thank you for your help

Comment: Good luck Maxsanc1! :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a low-tech inefficient way of doing it. It should work if your file size is small enough. Not sure if this is what you want.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1)
Do While f.AtEndOfStream <> True
 thisLine = f.ReadLine
 If InStr(thisLine, searchWord) then
   MsgBox "Found: " & thisLine
   Exit Do
 End If
Loop
f.Close
```

Comment: i'm not experienced enough, can you give me a more complete code for this :/ I'm in the process of learning the basics of js right now cuz the other friend suggested me to do so :D. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

This a vbscript from the original code : http://jacxl.free.fr/cours_xl/vbs/moteur_rech.vbs

Just, i update some features on it like :

1. Added feature the
   **BrowseForFolder function** to make it more user friendly and easy to
   handle script.

[image]

2. The search result is a **HTA file type** instead of an HTML file type
   created in the temporary folder.
3. Added **Explore() function** embedded in HTML to explore each file share
   in Windows Explorer.
4. Adding **HtmlEscape() function**.
5. Adding **a waiting bar in HTA** when searching for users wait.

[image]

[image]

***Search_engine.vbs***

```
'**********************************************************************************
'Description du script VBS : Rechercher dans le contenu des fichiers de type texte
'**********************************************************************************
'En balayant les fichiers de type "fichiers texte" (fichiers ".txt",".htm",".asp",".php",".rtf",".html",".htm",".hta",".xml",".csv",".vbs" etc...),
'de les ouvrir les uns après les autres pour en extraire la portion de texte contenant le mot recherché.
'Le petit moteur peut toutefois rendre service pour explorer (en local) de petits sites Intranet (sans indexation préalable des pages).
'Code Original ==> http://jacxl.free.fr/cours_xl/vbs/moteur_rech.vbs
'***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
'- Mise à jour par Hackoo en 19/12/2013
'- Ajout d'une fonction pour parcourir le dossier à traiter par la fonction BrowseForFolder afin de rendre le script plus convivial et facile à manipuler
'- le résultat de la recherche est dans un fichier de type HTA au lieu dans un fichier de type HTML crée dans le dossier temporaire
'- Ajout de la fonction Explore() intégré dans le HTA pour explorer chaque fichier à part dans l'explorateur Windows
'- Ajout de la fonction HtmlEscape()
'***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
'- Mise à jour par Hackoo en 07/03/2014
'- Ajout d'une barre d'attente en HTA lors de la recherche pour faire patienter l'utilisateur
'***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
On Error Resume Next
Dim ws,Titre,MsgTitre,MsgAttente,oExec,Temp,Copyright,Size
dim tabl()
dim tablold()
redim tabl(1)
tabl(0)="jetpack"
num=1
nbtot=0
nboct=0
nbssrep=0
Copyright = "(Version modifié © Hackoo)"
Titre = "Recherche dans le contenu des fichiers de type texte " & Copyright
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
'choix du répertoire
nomrep = Parcourir_Dossier()
'choix du mot recherché
mot_cherch=inputbox("Taper le mot pour effectuer la recherche ?",Titre,"Wscript")
MsgTitre = "Recherche dans le contenu des fichiers de type texte " & Copyright
MsgAttente = "Veuillez patienter.la recherche du mot <FONT COLOR='yellow'><B>" & DblQuote(mot_cherch) & "</B></FONT> est en cours..."
If mot_cherch = "" Then WScript.Quit

'traiter le cas où nomrep est un disque ou un nom non valide
'if not fs.folderexists(nomrep) then 'or ucase(fs.getdrivename(nomrep))=ucase(replace(nomrep,"\","")) then
'    MsgBox "nom de répertoire non valide"
'    wscript.quit
'end if
tabl(1)=nomrep

'créer le fichier texte et l'ouvrir en appending
Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2)
Dim tempfile : tempFile = tempFolder & "\liste_fichiers.hta"
'msgbox tempFile
fichresult = tempFile 
Set nouv_fich = fs.OpenTextFile(fichresult,2,true,-1)
nouv_fich.close
Set nouv_fich = fs.OpenTextFile(fichresult,8,false,-1) 
Call CreateProgressBar(MsgTitre,MsgAttente)'Creation de barre de progression
Call LancerProgressBar()'Lancement de la barre de progression
StartTime = Timer 'Debut du Compteur Timer
nouv_fich.writeline("<html><title>"&Titre&"</title><HTA:APPLICATION SCROLL=""yes"" WINDOWSTATE=""Maximize""icon=""verifier.exe"">"&_
"<meta content=""text/html; charset=UTF-8"" http-equiv=""content-type"">"&_
"<body text=white bgcolor=#1234568><style type='text/css'>"&_
"a:link {color: #F19105;}"&_
"a:visited {color: #F19105;}"&_
"a:active {color: #F19105;}"&_
"a:hover {color: #FF9900;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}"&_
"</style>")
nouv_fich.writeline "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript"">"
nouv_fich.writeline "Function Explore(filename)"
nouv_fich.writeline "Set ws=CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
nouv_fich.writeline "ws.run ""Explorer /n,/select,""&filename&"""""
nouv_fich.writeline "End Function"
nouv_fich.writeline "</script>"

'boucler sur les niveaux jusqu'à ce qu'il n'y ait 
'plus de sous répertoires dans le niveau
do while num>0 '------------------------------------

'recopie tabl
    redim tablold(ubound(tabl))
    for n=0 to ubound(tabl)
        tablold(n)=tabl(n)
    next

'réinitialiser tabl
    redim tabl(0)
    tabl(0)="zaza"

'explorer le ss répertoire
    for n=1 to ubound(tablold)
        expl(tablold(n)) 'ajoute ds le tableau tabl les ss rep de tablold(n)
    next
loop '----------------------------------------------

nouv_fich.writeline("</BODY></HTML>")
nouv_fich.close
Call FermerProgressBar()'Fermeture de barre de progression
DurationTime = FormatNumber(Timer - StartTime, 0) & " seconds." 'La duree de l'execution du script

Set Dossier = fs.getfolder(nomrep)
SizeKo = Round(FormatNumber(Dossier.Size)/(1024),2) & " Ko" 'Taille en Ko avec 2 chiffres apres la Virgule
 SizeMo = Round(FormatNumber(Dossier.Size)/(1048576),2) & " Mo" 'Taille en Mo avec 2 chiffres apres la Virgule
 SizeGo = Round(FormatNumber(Dossier.Size)/(1073741824),2) & " Go" 'Taille en Go avec 2 chiffres apres la Virgule

 If Dossier.size < 1024 Then
     Size = Dossier.size & " Octets"
 elseif Dossier.size < 1048576 Then
     Size = SizeKo
 elseif Dossier.size < 1073741824 Then
     Size = SizeMo
 else
     Size = SizeGo
 end If
set nouv_fich=nothing
If Err <> 0 Then
     'MsgBox Err.Number & VbCrLF & Err.Description,16,MsgTitre
     On Error GoTo 0
 End if
'nboct2= int(fs.getfolder(nomrep).size/1024/1024)
set fs=nothing 
'afficher le résultat dans un Popup
Ws.Popup "La recherche est terminée en "& DurationTime & " !"& vbCr &_
"Recherche effectuée dans " & vbCrLF & nbtot & " fichiers pour " & Size & " dans " & DblQuote(nomrep) &_
" et ses " & nbssrep & " sous-répertoires (total " & Size & ")","6",MsgTitre,64

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
sh.run "explorer " & fichresult
set sh=nothing
'*************************************************************************
Function Parcourir_Dossier()
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Veuillez choisir un dossier pour la recherche " & Copyright,1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    NomDossier = objFolder.title
    Parcourir_Dossier = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'*************************************************************************
sub expl(nomfich) 
'ajoute dans le tableau tabl() tous les sous répertoires de nomfich
'et ajoute dans le fichier nouv_fich les noms des fichiers et leurs caractéristiques

    Set rep=fs.getFolder(nomfich)
    num=ubound(tabl)
'parcourir les sous répertoires de nomfich
    for each ssrep in rep.subfolders 
        num=num+1 
        redim preserve tabl(num)
        tabl(num)= ssrep.path
        nbssrep=nbssrep+1
    next 
'parcourir les fichiers de nomfich
    for each fich in rep.files 
        nbtot=nbtot+1
        nboct=nboct+fich.size
'**********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
'chercher dans le fichier (vous pouvez commenter cette ligne si vous voulez juste afficher les fichiers qui contient seulement le mot à rechercher)
'nouv_fich.writeline fich.path & "<br><FONT COLOR=""yellow""><B>(" & int(fich.size/1024) & " ko, cr&eacute;&eacute; " & fich.DateCreated & ", acc " & fich.DateLastAccessed & ")</B></FONT><br>"
'**********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
        Dim Ext 
'ici dans ce tableau vous pouvez ajouter d'autres extensions de type texte
        Ext = Array(".txt",".asp",".php",".rtf",".html",".htm",".hta",".xml",".csv",".vbs",".js",".css",".ini",".inf")
        For i=LBound(Ext) To UBound(Ext)
            if instr(lcase(fich.name),Ext(i)) > 0 Then 
                Set fich_sce = fs.OpenTextFile(fich.path,1,false,-2)
                txtlu=fich_sce.readall
                txtlu = HtmlEscape(txtlu)
                fich_sce.close
'txtlu=tt(txtlu)
                pos=instr(lcase(txtlu),lcase(mot_cherch))
                if pos>0 then 
                    nouv_fich.writeline ("<HR><A href=""#"" OnClick='Explore("""& fich.Path & """)'>" & fich.Path & "</A>")
                    do while pos>0
                        nbav=50
                        if pos-1<nbav then nbav=pos-1
                        nbapr=50
                        if len(txtlu)-pos-len(mot_cherch)+1<nbapr then nbapr=len(txtlu)-pos-len(mot_cherch)+1
                        txx= tt(mid(txtlu,pos-nbav,nbav)) & "<FONT COLOR='Yellow'><B>" & tt(mid(txtlu,pos,len(mot_cherch))) & "</B></FONT>" & mid(txtlu,pos+len(mot_cherch),nbapr)
                        if nbav=50 then txx="..." & txx
                        if nbapr=50 then txx=txx & "..."
                        txx="<BR>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" & txx
                        nouv_fich.writeline txx
                        txtlu=right(txtlu,len(txtlu)-pos+1-len(mot_cherch))
                        pos=instr(lcase(txtlu),lcase(mot_cherch))
                    loop
                end if
            end if
        next 
    next
    set rep=nothing 
end sub
'*************************************************************************
function tt(txte)
    tt=txte
    tt=replace(tt,"<","&lt;")
    tt=replace(tt,">","&gt;")
end function
'*************************************************************************
Function HtmlEscape(strRawData) 
'http://alexandre.alapetite.fr/doc-alex/alx_special.html
    Dim strHtmlEscape 
    strHtmlEscape = strRawData
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, "&", "&amp;")
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, "<", "&lt;")
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, ">", "&gt;")
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, """", "&quot;")
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, "à", "&agrave;")
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, "è", "&egrave;")
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, "é", "&eacute;")
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, "©", "&copy;")
    strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, "ê", "&ecirc;")
'strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, vbCrLf, "<br>")
'strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, vbCr, "<br>")
'strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, vbLf, "<br>")
'strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, vbTab, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
'strHtmlEscape = Replace(strHtmlEscape, "  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;")
    HtmlEscape = strHtmlEscape
End Function
'****************************************************************************************************
Sub CreateProgressBar(Titre,MsgAttente)
    Dim ws,fso,f,f2,ts,ts2,Ligne,i,fread,LireTout,NbLigneTotal,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta,oExec
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\Barre.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<Title>  " & Titre & "</Title>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<HTA:APPLICATION"
    fhta.WriteLine "ICON = ""magnify.exe"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "BORDER=""THIN"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "INNERBORDER=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MAXIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "MINIMIZEBUTTON=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SCROLL=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SYSMENU=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SELECTION=""NO"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "SINGLEINSTANCE=""YES"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "</HEAD>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<BODY text=""white""><CENTER><DIV><SPAN ID=""ProgressBar""></SPAN>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<span><marquee DIRECTION=""LEFT"" SCROLLAMOUNT=""3"" BEHAVIOR=ALTERNATE><font face=""Comic sans MS"">" & MsgAttente &"</font></marquee></span></DIV></CENTER></BODY></HTML>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""VBScript""> "
    fhta.WriteLine "Set ws = CreateObject(""wscript.Shell"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(""%Temp%"")"
    fhta.WriteLine "Sub window_onload()"
    fhta.WriteLine "    CenterWindow 480,90"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Self.document.bgColor = ""1234568"" "
    fhta.WriteLine " End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine " Sub CenterWindow(x,y)"
    fhta.WriteLine "    Dim iLeft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.resizeTo x,y"
    fhta.WriteLine "    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2"
    fhta.WriteLine "    window.moveTo ileft,itop"
    fhta.WriteLine "End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "</script>"
    fhta.close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub LancerProgressBar()
    Set oExec = Ws.Exec("mshta.exe " & Temp & "\Barre.hta")
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub FermerProgressBar()
    oExec.Terminate
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Hi I really appreciate this. Can i ask for something  can you edit this that i can give only one file to search not an entire directory because i want it to be fast and if possible can u make the prefered file to be saved so i dont choose jt everytime? It can be in the code only so i can edit the directory to the file and it'll do the job. Also can u remove the found in "" seconds window so it opens the results immediately. I really appreciate this but as i said i need it to be efficient. Thanks very much

Comment: And im assuming the result page has a text limit per line. Can u remove or increase that i really appreciate it thanks